# Throws Null pointer Exception in java

Tags: java

```
## Class B ##
    public class ClassB{

    public ClassB() {
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return "Address";
    }
      }

## Class A ##
    public class ClassA{
    private ClassB classb;

    public ClassA() {
    }

    public void setClassb(ClassB classb) {
    this.classb = classb;
}
    public void getAddress() {
         System.out.println(classb.getAddress());
    }
      }

## Main Class ##
        public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassA classa = new ClassA();
        classa.getAddress();
    }}


----------
```

When I run this program, it return nullpointer exception. Can somebody please explain me the reason for the Nullpointer Exception? Thank you. I have tried use setter method but still throw nullpointer exception

Comment: I'd prefer you to close this question, as this might serve a small audience on this site.

Comment: You haven't created the `classB` object. You have just  declared it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classb` is just a reference variable which will point to a object. To get anything done from ClassB, you first need to create the object of the class as shown below

solution 1:

```
//initialize at the time of declaration
private ClassB classb = new ClassB();
```

solution 2 :

```
//provide a setter method: 
private ClassB classb;
public void setClassb(ClassB classb)
{
     this.classb= classb;
}
```

**EDIT**:

in your main class

instead of these statements :

```
    ClassA classa = new ClassA();
    classa.getAddress();
```

try with these statements:

```
    ClassA classa = new ClassA();
    classa.setClassb(new ClassB());//new statement to be inserted!
    classa.getAddress();
```

Comment: solution 2 :

//provide a setter method: 
private ClassB classb; 

this is constructor or setter method?
public setClassB(ClassB classb)
{
     this.classb= classb;
}

Comment: This is a setter method not a constructor. My bad. I have edited the code.

Comment: your solution 2 is constructor or setter method? Setter method must has return type of void right?

Comment: but i have try used setter method, but it still throws nullpointer exception

Comment: @gjman2 I have edited the my answer to show how to use the how to use setter method. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

The `classB` instance inside ClassA is not instiated.

You have to instantiate the ClassB when creating ClassA instance

```
public class ClassA{
private ClassB classb;

public ClassA() {
    classb = new ClassB()
}

public void getAddress() {
     System.out.println(classb.getAddress());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`classb` is declared in your `ClassA`, but it's not initialized, so when you try `classb.getAddress()`, you get a `NullPointerException`. You can initialize it in your constructor for `ClassA`:

```
 public ClassA() 
 {
    classb = new ClassB();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

fix this by:

```
    public class ClassA{
    private ClassB classb = new ClassB(); //initialize

    public ClassA() {
    }

    public void getAddress() {
         System.out.println(classb.getAddress());
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's due to your `classb` member in `classa` not being initialized. To correct this you can either initialize it when you initialize a ClassA object or, since you're returning a static value from ClassB's getAddress() method, make the getAddress() method of ClassB static, don't bother initializing a ClassB object, and reference the ClassB's getAddress() method statically from ClassA's getAddress() method.

Example:

```
// Class B
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB()
    {
    }

    public static String getAddress()
    {
        return "Address";
    }
}


// Class A
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
    }

    public void getAddress()
    {
        System.out.println(ClassB.getAddress());
    }
}


// Main Class
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassA classa = new ClassA();
        classa.getAddress();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ClassA the ClassB is not initialized

private ClassB classb = new ClassB();

Take a look http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html